# restrict the data fetching in single hit from database in SSRS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

i am using SSRS reports to load the reports which have multiple pages and nearly 300k records. since SSRS fetching the 300k records in single hit, performance getting very bed . **is there any way to get the records like by clicking NEXT or moving to next page**. **for example** first page should have only 100 records and my stored procedure should return only 100 records  and when i am moving to the second page again i want to get another 100 records from the database should load in second page .

Comment: i am facing the same problem, and i have not been able to bring data on next page click , is there any concept of caching in ssrs which can help

Comment: Good question, but no you can't do this in SSRS.